# posting to google plus through api

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-apis-explorer

Trying to find how to post to google plus wall from PHP but got 403 even using the api explorer [at](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plusDomains/v1/plusDomains.activities.insert?userId=me&preview=true&_h=4&resource=%257B%250A%20%20%2522access%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%2522items%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522type%2522%253A%20%2522domain%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%255D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%2522domainRestricted%2522%253A%20true%250A%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%2522object%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%2522originalContent%2522%253A%20%2522something%2522%250A%20%20%257D%250A%257D&) got the

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

My PHP code looks like:

```
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Speerit");
    $client->setClientId($appId);
    $client->setClientSecret($appSecret);
    $client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
    $client->setAccessToken(
        json_encode(
            array(
                'access_token' => $accessToken,
                'expires_in' => 3600,
                'token_type' => 'Bearer',
            )
        )
    );
    $client->setScopes(
        array(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write",
        )
    );
    $client = $client->authorize();

    // create the URL for this user ID
    $url = sprintf('https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/me/activities');

    // create your HTTP request object
    $headers = ['content-type' => 'application/json'];
    $body = [
        "object" => [
            "originalContent" => "Happy Monday! #caseofthemondays",
        ],
        "access" => [
            "items" => [
                ["type" => "domain"],
            ],
            "domainRestricted" => true,
        ],
    ];
    $request = new Request('POST', $url, $headers, json_encode($body));

    // make the HTTP request
    $response = $client->send($request);

    // did it work??
    echo $response->getStatusCode().PHP_EOL;
    echo $response->getReasonPhrase().PHP_EOL;
    echo $response->getBody().PHP_EOL;
```

Following official documentation and some references from other posts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we need to understand that there is an API for free google accounts, meaning accounts ending **@gmail.com** and there is an API for G Suite accounts, meaning account ending @**yourdomain.com.** Based on the **[reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities)** and recent testings, it is not possible to insert a comment using the API on free google accounts *(@gmail.com)*.

This is only possible with G Suite accounts **(@yourdomain.com)**. I had to read the documentation for the **[insert method](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/activities/insert)**, and I was able to make it work by doing the following:

```
<?php session_start();

require_once "vendor/autoload.php"; //include library

//define scopes required to make the api call
    $scopes = array(
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"
);

// Create client object
$client = new Google_Client(); 
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/index.php');
$client->setAuthConfig("client_secret.json");
$client->addScope($scopes);

if( isset($_SESSION["access_token"]) ) {

  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION["access_token"]);
  $service = new Google_Service_PlusDomains($client);

  $activity = new Google_Service_PlusDomains_Activity(
    array(
      'access' => array(
          'items' => array(
              'type' => 'domain'
          ),
          'domainRestricted' => true
      ),
      'verb' => 'post',
      'object' => array(
          'originalContent' => "Post using Google API PHP Client Library!" 
      ), 
    )
  );

  $newActivity = $service->activities->insert("me", $activity);


  var_dump($newActivity);


} else {

  if( !isset($_GET["code"]) ){

    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

  } else {

    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
      $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

      $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/index.php';
      header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

  }
}

?>
```

In summary, if you try to do this on a free gmail.com account, you will get the  403 Forbidden error. Hopefully in the future this will be available but for right now, only companies that have partnered with Google has access to this special api, such as Hootsuite.

Comment: i execute your code with my app credentials and got the same response { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden", "message": "Forbidden" } ], "code": 403, "message": "Forbidden" } }

Comment: Revoke access to the app and then try again. Also, are you using a GSuite account? @bitgandtter

Comment: I revoke it and returns the same message. for some reason i cannot share. Im using my personal account

Comment: @bitgandtter If you are using your personal **@gmail.com** account, then I guess it is not possible. According to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities), there is no **insert method** for the activity resource. I haven't give it a try yet but I'll do and then I'll confirm this.

Comment: Thanks @morfinismo, if for some reason you manage to get it to work, please let me know. Thanks a lot

Comment: @bitgandtter I have updated the answer. There is no possible way to do it on a free gmail.com account.

Comment: But hootsuite.com will support post the data on google plus using normal gamil account