# What exactly is needed to post on Google plus with their API

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-plus, google-api-php-client, google-domain-api

My question is about [Google + Domains API](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/) :

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272963/how-to-post-on-google-plus-pages-through-api#answer-14278367) is said : "Currently, there is no publicly available API to post to Google+".

So search for other so many Q&A i see the possibility to POST with Google + Domains API through Google domain account.

So again so many doubts appeared :

1- What is Google Domain account and how set this to propose of POST on Google Plus(Perfil/Page or Communities)?

I learn about [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) and [git google respositore php class library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services/tree/master/src/Google/Service/PlusDomains).

In some tests(from localhost), i got get authorization and acessToken, but ever with errors like that on the end : Forbidden or Invalid Credentials.

On my searchs the error is becouse i dont try with the Google Domain Acccount.

So i dont see in all google results the way to made that end to end, from create Google Account Domain to POST on Google Plus.

I'm not asking for one complete tutorial, just the way to a i do that.

After 5 days in row, here is my last attempt(or not who knows), but I'm tired and cant see the light on the end of tunnel.

Any tips are welcome.

sorry my english

Comment: Possible duplicate of [posting to google plus through api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742869/posting-to-google-plus-through-api)

Comment: I start understand that, still learn Google accounts now... Tks for this  poiting @Morfinismo