# How to post to google plus profile using api?

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus, google-plus-domains

I am currently developing a website which helps to post directly on social networks. But I couldn't post to a Google plus profile. I searched the whole Google+ API developer document, but I couldn't find out any api to post in a Google plus profile.

I even tried Google Domains API for posting, but that was too domain restricted. I know some types of Google plus APIs are only available for their partners. I can post to a google plus page, since I have access to that APIs. But how to post in a profile. Is there any other API which is restricted to public for profile posting. I think many applications such as Buffer and Hootsuite can post to Google plus profile.

Comment: Please follow this post. Might be helpful for you:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742869/posting-to-google-plus-through-api

Comment: @KuldeepSingh thats google domains and not google+ it is not helpful

Answer (score 0):

The [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/) is currently read only.  Which means you cant post to it google+ programmaticly.   There is probably a private API that Google allows some sites to use.  This is not public and i have never seen anyone get access to it.

The only option you have is the Google+ sharing button [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/)  which is not a believe what you are looking for.

```
<!-- Place this tag in your head or just before your close body tag. -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

<!-- Place this tag where you want the share button to render. -->
<div class="g-plus" data-action="share"></div>
```

Comment: But apps like Buffer, Hootsuite can directly post to Google plus.

Comment: These apps probably have an agreement with Google.  If your company is that big.  Then your company probably already has some contacts from within Google You may want to contact them directly.  There is no public API  for the average developer to use to post to Google+

Comment: Sorry that i could not be of more assistance.  I have wanted to post to google plus for years as well.