# Not able to post data on google plus page using normal gmail account

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client, google-client

I have created an app  by using g suite account . Using google client API , I can  able to post the data on google plus  page using my g suite account. It's fine. But I need to post the data on google plus page normal gmail account. When I tried to post the data using my normal test.gmail.com. Its provided following error.

> (Something went wrong: Error calling POST
>   https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/me/activities: (403)
>   Forbidden). But Hootsuite site  I can able to post data on google plus
>   by using normal gmail account . Shall I need to purchase any other
>   like (g suite account).

Reference Link :-

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

My Scopes :

```
$client>addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.write");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.media.upload");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profiles.read");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.read");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/activity");
```

Or shall I use some more scope?

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742869/posting-to-google-plus-through-api/42754302#42754302

Comment: I tried with this account, ads@yourdomain.com. But unable to post in google plus.